# how find named colors except "transparent" by using regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to find

1. all background colors with names ("red", "blue" etc.),
2. except "none" and "transparents".
3. And these should not be commented out by  "//".

Unfortunately, with this regEx I still find "**transparent**":

```
(^\s*background:\s*)[a-z]{3,10};
```

Source code example:

```
background: #fff; // should not be found
background: transparents; // should not be found, but is found
// background: blue; // should not be found
background: blue; // should be found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
^\s*background:\s*(?!transparents|none)[a-z]{3,};
```

I changed the match to not bound the length, since `transparents` wouldn't have matched anyway as is *12* characters long (not 10 as your regex specified).

I also removed unnecessary brackets.

Comment: do you prever `[a-z]+;`or `[a-z]{3,12}`; ? why `[a-z]{3,12}`

Comment: @sl5 I prefer `[a-z]{3,}`, which means “at least 3 letters, as it seems a good fit. As for other alternatives, there’s not much difference - go for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Within a large CSS `^` anchor wouldn't work. Try `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` in PCRE:

```
//\N*(*SKIP)(*F)|background:\s*(?!transparent|none)\w+
```

This cares about commented lines as well. Your current regex doesn't exclude any thing. It should benefit from a negative lookahead as PCRE supports these kind of constructs.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WvOGJ8/2)

Comment: for some reason regex101 shows timeout (https://imgur.com/a/GmZM9l0) and i could not test your regex inside regex101 ( https://regex101.com/r/WvOGJ8/2 ) and inside jetbrains IDE its not work (  https://imgur.com/a/nzcUlEy ).

Comment: @SL5net Jetbrains' regex flavor isn't PCRE and you tagged your question with PCRE which means special verbs used in this answer don't work in there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and instead of `{3,10}` you could use a `+` to match one or more times a character.

[`(^\s*background:\s*)(?!\b(?:none|transparent)\b)[a-z]+;`](https://regex101.com/r/6qRLRX/2)

You might also omit the parenthesis around `(^\s*background:\s*)` if you are not referring to that group anymore.

Comment: Yes i mean transparent not transparents. i will updat that i the question. thanks